# Why use Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME

Tags: android, android-intent

while reading Android docs about Widgets I stumbled upon this piece of code whose purpose is to launch a service for retrieving a factory for StackView items.

```
// Set up the intent that starts the StackViewService, which will
// provide the views for this collection.
Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
// Add the app widget ID to the intent extras.
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
// Instantiate the RemoteViews object for the App Widget layout.
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
// Set up the RemoteViews object to use a RemoteViews adapter. 
// This adapter connects
// to a RemoteViewsService  through the specified intent.
// This is how you populate the data.
rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stack_view, intent);
```

You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider-collections)

I have a problem understanding why do you need to call

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```

I understand that it gives URI a prefix *intent://*, but is it necessary here?

Comment: fas as i understand it, it creates a uri pointing to the intent itself.

Comment: Or perhaps more to the point that the "data"--which do get compared for uniqueness--ends up containing the previously set "extras" which do not.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.

Brief: If don't used: it will display the same id for all instances of the widget, if you don't use setData.